# Skip NaN values while counting data in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to get the count of the Text type data and to find out the top 5 among the given data.

Input file is as follows:

```
Gears of war 3
Gears of war
Assassin creed
.......
.......
Crysis 2
Gears of war3
Sims
```

My Output is as follows:

```
{
    'Gears of War 3': 6,
    'Batman': 5,
    'gears of war 3': 4,
    'Rocksmith': 5,
    'nan': 32870
}
```

I want my code to skip counting nan values in my csv file.

My code is as follows:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('D:\my_file.csv')

for colname, dtype in data.dtypes.to_dict().iteritems():
    if dtype == 'object':
        print colname
        count = Counter(data[colname])
        d = dict((str(k), v) for k, v in count.iteritems())
        f = dict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)[:5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `value_counts()` to count the non-`Nan` values:

```
        one       two     three
a  0.196508 -0.465768 -0.710062
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c  0.532602  1.835499  0.465047
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e  0.175336 -0.471934 -1.517812
f -2.392756 -0.021330 -0.239647
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h -0.612554  0.238613 -1.060184

df2['one'].value_counts()

 0.532602    1
 0.196508    1
 0.175336    1
-0.612554    1
-2.392756    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete `nan` item from the Counter instance which is dictionary-like object:

```
from numpy import nan
del count[nan]
```

BTW You can use `Counter.most_common` method:

```
f = count.most_common(5)
```

Comment: Christopher thanks a lot for the quick reply 
del count['nan'] is not working.. I tried it

Comment: why do you want to iterate over the frame instead of using existing methods? or am i missing something?

Comment: user1667967, I thought that `nan` is represented by string `"nan"`, but it's `numpy.nan`; I edited my answer